# Ms Excel or Apple Numbers import rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers, filemaker

I have an Excel file from which I need to export specific colums and place them in a separate file. Is there a program in Windows or Mac, which allows me to set the rules and have these saved for further re-use, so that I can define which column data from FILE 1 goes into which column from FILE 2?

In addition, I also need to change some date formating, for example from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYYMMDD in certain columns. If I can automate this process and have it saved as a rule, it will be great.

The reason I need to save these "rules" is because I am working with a data Excel file which will later need to be updated with current data, reason why a second import or a new freshly updated import will need to be done.

I have access to a Windows computer with Excel 2010, and a Mac with Excel 2011 and Numbers 09. I also have Filemaker 11 in case it may be easier to accomplish this here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a separate Workbook that reference your original file (and performs certain formatting)?

E.g. fill the required cells in the new workbook with references like this:

```
=[Workbook1]Sheet1!A1
```

That way an "export" can easily be made by opening the referencing workbook which would automatically use fresh data, and then copy/paste as values somewhere to freeze the values.